# Looking for meaningful review of Leapwork

Tags: automated-testing, test-design, tools, web

So I'm currently researching and comparing `test automation tools`, that would automate tests on the `web` (as in, testing a web site), and are relatively cheap and simple.

One such tool I'm looking at is [LeapWork](https://leapwork.com).  But all I've found review-wise are 2 blogs, where both are short and high-level, and one of them is even from `LeapWork's` site.

Has anyone here used `LeapWork` before?  If so, what are the pros and cons you've experienced in using `LeapWork`?  Are there also other tools you've used and how do they compare?

I do plan on using the trial myself, but I always like getting other peoples' opinions.

Comment: If you are testing a website, any reason you don't want to use Selenium? I mean it is basically the web testing standard tool.

Comment: @Andarta Leaptest advertises itself to be for non-coders.

Comment: @ChrisKenst, I'm not saying I don't want to use Selenium...I'm seeing what options are out there and comparing.  Right now what I'm seeing in comparing Selenium and LeapTest is Selenium is free but with LeapTest we could utilize users in creating the tests and doing so is quicker and easier.

Comment: You can always write a framework to go with Selenium.  If you don't want to code a framework and you want to purchase there are a ton of purchased test automation tools...not just LeapTest.

Comment: Every tool for non-coders will create crappy and hard to modify "replay actions" script which will be hard to refactor to something maintainable using pageObject design pattern. Don't waste your time, learn programming. See http://www.jamesshore.com/Blog/The-Problems-With-Acceptance-Testing.html

Comment: Non coder 'write a framework' ?  Tons of?  I actually don't see tons.  OUtside of selenium, maybe testng, testComplete and Watir.  Yiou'll see a fair number listed at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_testing_tools but in reality many are older or abandoned.  Use Selenium.  Use the IDE if you come from not programming, or language and test frameworks such as Ruby-Rspec-Capybara if you can program or want to get started.

Comment: Yes i agree with @PeterMasiar the simpler tools will end up being more painful, and you'll discover that writing test automation requires programming skills.  Whatever tools you use, once you start to have complexity - multiple cases and suites, dozens and hundreds of page locators, you'll grind to a halt without a way to organize them.  That way is programming.

Comment: @Andarta I believe you are wrong if you think users will write tests for you. See my previous link. We tried to use Fit (with similar hopes) and users just did not wrote any tests, so programmers were forced to use crappy "non-programming" language instead of real one.

Comment: lol, yes I see that Michael, my comment didn't make alot of sense, I misread it thinking that they were a coder, but wanted to include non coders to be able to help out.  I have written a framework abstraction that gets non-coders to easily code in Selenium and the IDE intellisence prompts them so they don't get lost.  Non-technical testers were able to write automation with minimal training...but that requires someone to write that for them...

Comment: Additional point: if all you found about a tool are two blog posts, which are high-level, it is pretty sure bet there is no much community around such tool. OTOH, Selenium has *huge community*, as it is W3C standard for browser automation. So it has binding for many languages, and you can find answers to many questions on SO. **Especially** if you are not an expert, you want to use whatever everyone else is using.

Comment: @mutt, yeah, actually - I am a coder, and we already have a user that does do some test case writing for manual testing. But if I have to code something anyway, I'd rather just code the tests myself (I can ensure better test coverage anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaptest focus seems to be as a visual recognition type tools.

These tools are usually fairly limited in functionality and create tests that are fragile and easily broken by page changes.

When using selectors to identify parts of the web page, currently a human programmer will make the best decision, ensuring that the locator is robust, unique and not tied into the page layout

Example: Sometimes `table tr td td td` would be auto generated by such a tool as a unique identifier but which table cell to use will actually change over time as the table output, layout and content gets changed and what would work much better would be `table#todays_selection td.edit_current_amount`, i.e. using classes and ID's to narrow down the right element.  This assumes that suitable classes, ID's, data attributes, etc. exist on the page.  If they don't exist or are used sparingly you will have to be selective in which you use, will require developers to improve identification of elements or, worst choice, you will have to use include layout tags in your tests making them more brittle and likely to break when the pages get changed for non-related reasons.

My advice would be to start using the Firefox seleniumIDE plugin.
When you outgrow it, use ruby-rspec-selenium which is my tool of choice.

Answer (score 2):

I am a software tester with no programming skills (and I'm not even very tech savvy). My role in our small company is to manually test web apps under development and automate regression testing for updates to our products in production. LeapTest has been fantastic for regression testing. It is very simple to use and not once have I had to ask a programmer for assistance. I am currently investigating how to integrate LeapTest into our Dev stream. Once we have Dev, QA, Staging, and Prod environments setup, I think we can use LeapTest open API to automate Dev work. I will likely need a little help with the integration, but I have found LeapTest support to extremely responsive, helpful, and patient.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using LeapTest for about two years and did successful integration in Dev cycles with use of **Jenkins** CI. It is flexible enough to create and organize your test scripts and utilities strong as required. If you go with bad approach, the tool chosen doesn't matter much. Cons that I found from my experience with the tool are:

1. Bad debugging capabilities
2. Database unit has very basic capabilities - no multiple queries
3. No script execution( workaround - WIN cmd, powershell support)
4. Javascript unit - no external library references.

If you're interested about the complete solution, you can contact me on skype: kvazimodu. I would be glad to share experience